# Excel VBA: How to compare if values appear in both columns and copy its adjacent cell values to another column?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to search 2 set of data (from Jul and Aug) and compare to get results

1. countries appear in Jul and Aug
2. countries appear in Jul and not in Aug
3. Calculate the percentage increase or decrease on the count value for country (appearing in Jul and Aug)

Below is the excel screenshot i'm referring to

1. Take the value 'America' in cell A2 and search in column E
2. If found, copy the values in Cell A1, B1 And C1 to column H1, I1 & J1

Question

1. Now I want to copy the value in column F to column K (if same country appear in Aug and Jul).
2. For example for Cananda search , my code logic can copy the values in same row but not in cell F2 (cos different row)? Any ideas to share how to do it?

[image]

Below is my VBA codes

```
Sub Compare()
Dim Report As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, fVal As Range, c As Range, i As Long
Set Report = Sheets(1) 'Edit sheet name
lastRow = Report.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'For Each c In Report.Range("A2:A10") 'Assumes header row
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        'Set fVal = Report.Range("E2:E" & lastRow).Find(c.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        Set fVal = Report.Range("E2:E" & lastRow).Find(Report.Cells(i, 1).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If Not fVal Is Nothing Then
                'c.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                Report.Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                Report.Cells(i, 8) = Report.Cells(i, 1)
                Report.Cells(i, 9) = Report.Cells(i, 2)
                Report.Cells(i, 10) = Report.Cells(i, 3)
            Else
                Report.Cells(i, 13) = Report.Cells(i, 1)
                Report.Cells(i, 14) = Report.Cells(i, 2)
            End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you want. Have shortened the code a little too using Resize. You need to refer to your found cell (in this case one cell to the right as I understand it).

```
Sub Compare()

Dim Report As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, fVal As Range, c As Range, i As Long

Set Report = Sheets(1) 'Edit sheet name
lastRow = Report.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        Set fVal = Report.Range("E2:E" & lastRow).Find(Report.Cells(i, 1).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not fVal Is Nothing Then
            Report.Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            Report.Cells(i, 8).Resize(, 3).Value = Report.Cells(i, 1).Resize(, 3).Value
            Report.Cells(i, 11).Value = fVal.Offset(, 1).Value
        Else
            Report.Cells(i, 13).Resize(, 2).Value = Report.Cells(i, 1).Resize(, 2).Value
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey thanks. Thats fast response from you. Thank you very much. it works. Will go and read up about resize and offset